# Good methods to solve: $ \int _{0}^{\pi/2} \ln^4 (2 \sin x )\ \mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I have a question which asks to find:

$\displaystyle \tag*{} \int \limits_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln^4 (2 \sin x)\  \mathrm dx$

There are few solutions to this integral already such as using Fourier series for $x \in \left(0, \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$

$\displaystyle \tag*{} \ln(2\sin x) = - \sum \limits _{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos(2nx)}{n}$

and then integrating and proceeding. Also, there is another method involving differentiating $4$ times the known integral:

$\displaystyle \tag*{} \int \limits _0 ^{\pi} 2^k\sin^k x  \ \mathrm dx$

My question is whether there any other easy or faster methods to solve this integral?

Comment: Differentiating under the integral seems quite fast

Comment: $$ I=\frac{19\pi^5}{480}$$

Comment: @user178256 yes you are right! can you share your solution if you can?